# Trying to tokenize a string

Tags: c++, tokenize, end-of-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

I have this text file

```
q1 t q2

q2 e q3

q3 x q4

q4 t q5 q6 q11

q5 | q6 q11
```

I want to extract each element that is separated by a space. For example, in line one I want to be able to extract "q1" "t" and "q2" as separate tokens.

I'm thinking there's two ways to go about this

1. read from the file, token by token, using ifstream>>. The problem I'm having with this approach is that I don't know how to tell when the end of a line has been reached so that I can move onto the next line.
2. The other approach, is to get the whole line at once with getline(); The problem with this approach is that I have to tokenize the string myself, and each line is different so I'm not sure that's the best idea. I'm pretty blown away there's no built in way to do this, besides strtok() which looks to be not at all what I want. Thanks guys any help is appreciated.

Comment: So do you want one giant linear array containing every token in the file? If so, the first one works fine, and can be augmented with `std::vector`'s constructor taking two iterators.

Comment: If you're tokens are as nicely separated by whitespace (including newlines) as this, `while (fs >> str)` will totally work for you.

Comment: Either your newlines have meaning. Then go for `getline()` and feed the line through stringstream to get tokens. Or your newlines *don't* have meaning, then reading from `ifstream` will ignore them like any other whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getline`, and to tokenize the resulting string, put it into a `std::stringstream` and extract the tokens from that.

```
std::string line_string;
while ( getline( file, line_string ) ) {
    std::istringstream line( line_string );
    std::string token;
    while ( line >> token ) {
        do something with token
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I would do also...  It's a great way to chuck together a simple configuration file when you're in a hurry =)

Comment: Awesome, trying that right now, looks easy!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use standard library, you can go with `getline` and then use a `stringstream` to `ifstream>>` it word by word.

Otherwise C++ is indeed quite limited in terms of text processing and you could do things more easily with Qt's [strings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html) and streams, or [string algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) from boost (including split), which integrate well with STL strings.